# JMSSerializerBundle: @Group not working on parent's parent class fields

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using JMSSerializerBundle to serialize my symfony entities to JSON. I have the following class structure:

```php
abstract class A {}
abstract class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
```

Now I want to serialize an object of class `C`, so I define a new Group, let's say "example_group", and set the `@Groups` annotation like this:

```php
abstract class A {
    /**
     * @Groups({"example_group"})
     */
    private $a1;

    private $a2;
}

abstract class B extends A {
    /**
     * @Groups({"example_group"})
     */
    private $b1;

    private $b2;
}

class C extends B {
    /**
     * @Groups({"example_group"})
     */
    private $c1;
}
```

The resulting serialization contains not only the `C::c1` field, but also `B::b1`, but surprisingly NOT `A::a1`. Is this the expected behaviour? I need also `A::a1` to be included. How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the `ExclusionPolicy` for the three classes.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy

/**
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
abstract class A 
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
abstract class B extends A 
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class C extends B
{
    // ...
}
```

By serializing `C` with the group `example_group`, you should get all the properties that are exposed through the `@Groups` annotation.

So for your instance you should have `$a1`, `$b1` and `$c1` rendered.

Comment: If I declare \@ExclusionPolicy("all") for all the classes, none of the attributes is rendered unless I explicitly declare \@expose for all the attributes I want to be serialized. Anyway, I tried doing so but I still can't see the $a attribute rendered (same result as before, $b and $c are correctly rendered). If I'm not wrong, \@ExclusionPolicy is not needed when you use \@Groups.

Comment: How do you set the group when you call the serializer?

Comment: This is how I set the group: $serializer->serialize($data, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('example_group')));

Comment: Where $groups is equal to array('example_group') ?

Comment: I think it's a bug, I'll implement your example and investigate, then I be back.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the base class User serialization metadata/config. For JMS Serializer, do something like:

```
#File: Model.User.yml

FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
exclusion_policy: ALL
access_type: public_method # defaults to property; can also be set per property
properties:
    email:
        expose: true
        type: string
        groups: [api]
    roles:
        expose: true
        type: array
        groups: [api]
```